# div position fixed but also need relative for child element

Tags: html, css, position

I tried to set a div position fixed for view it to bottom. But also need to position relative for positioning to child div 10px away from parent div.
Here is my HTML

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='inner'></div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
.container{
   position: fixed;
   position: relative; //this one will apply by priority
   bottom: 0;
   height: 400px;
   width: 400px;
}
.inner{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}
```

This code will not work as i expected.
How can i do this.

Comment: You can't set the same property more than once in a CSS rule

Comment: then what is the solution for it

Answer (score 1):

Any position [accept `static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning) works as a container for absolute positioned children. The problem in your case is the `bottom: 0`. As long as the viewport is smaller than the `.container`, the top part of the container is out of the screen. This makes the child to appear less than `50px` from the top.

Using [`position: relative`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Values) just ignored `bottom: 0`, since an offset of `0` does nothing.

After removing `bottom: 0`:

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background: silver;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">inner</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want container to set bottom of the screen

Comment: Don't use `position: relative` and make the `.container` smaller than the height of the viewport.